# state of currentPage is changing after coming back to page in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I am struggling to maintain the state of current page in vuex. I am tring to store the state of pagination when I click on any record and the on click of back button I should get the same page.

Below is the code snippest :

table.html

```
<b-table show-empty
             outlined
             hover
             stacked="md"
             :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
             :items="companies"
             :fields="[
                        {key: 'name', label: this.$t('shared.name'), sortable: true},
                        {key: 'companyId', label: this.$t('shared.orgNumber'), sortable: true},
                        {key: 'properties.state', label: this.$t('shared.status'), sortable: true},
                        {key: 'serviceProviderName', label: this.$t('shared.serProvider'), sortable: true}
                      ]"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :filter="filter"
             v-bind:empty-text='$t("shared.emptyText")'
             v-bind:empty-filtered-text='$t("shared.emptyFilteredText")'
             @filtered="onFiltered"
             @row-clicked="showCompany"
             tbody-tr-class="row-cursor">
    </b-table>

<b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage"
                  class="float-right"/>
```

in js file I have added computed like this :

```
computed: {

 currentPage:{
   get () {
     return this.$store.getters.currentPage;
   },
   set (value) {
     this.$store.commit('SET_CURRENT_PAGE', value);
   }
 },
},
```

Now the problem is when I am click on page number 2 and then click on any record and on click of record, new page is opening and then when I come back from that page I am not getting page number as 2. It is changing again to 1. In developer tool I can see it is storing the state but it is chaning when I come back to the page

I dont know why the state of currentPage is changing. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`currentPage` will reset after you leave the page.
To prevent such a behavior you should open record page in new window/tab or save the `currentPage` value in `cookies` or `localStorage`.
If you prefer the latter I would advice you to use [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have some doubt here. Do you mean vuex store will not work here? Actually in vuex store it is storing proper value but when I come back to page, it is again chaning the value of currentPage in vuex store. That means computed is triggering when I am coming back to page.

Comment: Vuex store resets every time you leave or refresh the page. Properties in `computed` are being triggered every time you load the page and every time when any of its dependencies being changed. So you come back to the page (which means you load it) and `computed` is being triggered.

Comment: I have tried this and now the table is correctly showing the 4th page of data, while the page number showing is 1. Page is 4th but the b-paggination is not synced with my currentPage value

Comment: Just noticed: you have to replace `:current-page="currentPage"` with `:current-page="$store.state.currentPage"`

Comment: b-table is displaying data of 4th page that means b-table is taking currentPage from store only. the problem is b-paggination is not chaning colour of 4th button, it is changing of 1st button. Now is there any way to forcefully change the colour of currentPage button in b-paggination?

Comment: Could you provide the full code? I think there must be a problem with defining a colour

Comment: thanks for your response, issue is resolved by using cookies and watch.  
    watch: {
    currentPage: function (v) {
      this.currentPage = this.$cookie.get('currentPage') != null ? parseInt(this.$cookie.get('currentPage')) : v;
    }
  },

Answer (score 0):

You should use @change attribute on your b-pagination component. If you bind it to a function returning items, it can use currentPage inside it to fetch the data for current page.

```
<b-pagination @change="fetchItems" ....>
```

Inside your component you could have a method

```
methods: {
   fetchItems () {
      // Use this.$store.getters.currentPage inside this function 
      // to fetch paginated data
      return items;
   }
}
```

You could also have a mount method to fetch paginated data using currentPage, this way you could fetch the data when you come back on page.

```
mounted () {
   fetchItems()
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but still it is reseting the value of current page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you leave the component it goes back to the ether.  When you come back to that component, the page is built again.  You should use the lifecycle hook created() to retrieve the saveed page from the store.  That way the currentPage variable will have the page set prior to rendering all of the elements.  It's probably better to use regular variable currentPage since there isn't a need for it to be a computed function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to maintain a flag to achieve this using store/vuex.
Take a look at the code below. I hope this is something you were looking for

```
<b-table show-empty
    outlined
    hover
    stacked="md"
    :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
    :items="companies"
    :fields="[
        {key: 'name', label: this.$t('shared.name'), sortable: true},
        {key: 'companyId', label: this.$t('shared.orgNumber'), sortable: true},
        {key: 'properties.state', label: this.$t('shared.status'), sortable: true}
    ]"
    :current-page="currentPage"
    :per-page="perPage"
    :filter="filter"
    v-bind:empty-text='$t("shared.emptyText")'
    v-bind:empty-filtered-text='$t("shared.emptyFilteredText")'
    @filtered="onFiltered"
    @row-clicked="showCompany"
    tbody-tr-class="row-cursor">
</b-table>

<b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage"
    class="float-right"/>

data() {
    return {
      vuexStateApplied: false
    }
  }

methods: {
    onFiltered(filteredItems) {
      if (!this.vuexStateApplied && !this._.isEmpty(this.$store.getters.currentPage)) {
        this.currentPage = this.$store.getters.currentPage

        // By setting this flag we are ensuring not to 
        // apply same currentPage value again on  
        // filtering the table data
        this.vuexStateApplied = true
      }
    }
}

beforeRouteLeave() {
    // update with new value
    this.$store.commit('SET_CURRENT_PAGE', value);
}

OR

destoryed() {
    // update with new value
    this.$store.commit('SET_CURRENT_PAGE', value);
}
```